# I want to backup last records of a table with mysqldump

Tags: php, mysql

So far I have this:

```
exec('mysqldump --user=$DBUSER --password=$DBPASSWD --host= localhost DB_NAME (select column from database.table where= column > 1234) > table.sql');
```

Of course nothing happens when I open the file on my server using a browser.
Now, the next code does output a SQL file but an empty one:

```
set_time_limit(600);
system("mysqldump -h localhost -u $DBUSER -p $DBPASSWD $DATABASE  > table.sql");
```

I'm after records generated every day so I can later do an incremental backup.

Why is it that `system()` does output a file and `exec()` doesn't?

Comment: In your first command there is a syntax error in the where clause.

Comment: If you want to do incremental backup this is not possible with mysqldump.

Comment: Ok, thanks... I've fixed the syntax error and made some changes:
    exec('mysqldump --host localhost --user $DBUSER --password $DBPASSWD $DATABASE "select * from table where column > \'1234\' " > table.sql');  it now outputs a file but, blank.

Comment: Well, actually the latter updates to the backup database will be done manually and selectively, not automatically, I just need every days separate records. :)

Comment: nobody haves an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your objective is to do incremental backups of your database `mysqldump` is not ideal option for it.

There are two things you might do here:

1. [BAD WAY] Use your PHP code to serialize and dump the new records in CSV and JSON format and use it.
2. You may want to use binlog in MySQL which will help you do it ([follow the link to read the MySQL backup methods](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html))

Dumping selective records:

```
$recset = mysql_query("select column from database.table where= column > 1234");
for($recset as $row){
    file_put_contents("filename.json", json_encode($row) . "\n")
}
```

Now, once neeed you may read this file line by line and use `json_enocode` to get you data back in php array/object and do as you wish with it.

[Edit: After looking at your pastebin code]

After fixing a few variable name and code to work as per your need.

```
$docsql='nts.sql';
require("cnxn.php");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$q1=mysqli_query($cnx,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE col > '45678' ORDER BY col ASC");
$data_records=array();
while($r1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q1)){
    $cntn=htmlentities($r1['cntn']);
    array_push($data_records, "(".$r1['col1'].",'".$r1['col2']."','".$r1['col3']."','".$r1['col4']."','".$r1['col5']."')");
}

$insert="INSERT INTO notas (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES ";
file_put_contents($docsql, $insert);
foreach($data_records as $record){
    file_put_contents($docsql, $record) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: Well, actually the latter updates to the backup database will be done manually and selectively, not automatically, I just need every days separate records. :)

Comment: In that case fastest way is you  write a `php`  script to filter the records and dump them using JSON or CSV format that you can use once needed.

Comment: Did that using file_put_contents, but line brakes come out as huge spaces between blocks of text and this makes it impossible to import back to my backup MySQL, trows syntax errors

Comment: please put the output on any pastebin so that i can fix it.

Comment: I really want to use the initial approach, i'ts more interesting and simple, I just need it to work (on the top of this question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90237/discussion-between-sam-ram-san-and-akm).

Answer (score 0):

To the solution that akm suggested, I just added a final touch to replace the last coma with a semicolon:

```
$docsql='nts.sql';
require("cnxn.php");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$q1=mysqli_query($cnx,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE col > '45678' ORDER BY col  ASC");
$data_records=array();
while($r1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q1)){
$cntn=htmlentities($r1['cntn']);
array_push($data_records, "(".$r1['col1'].",'".$r1['col2']."','".$r1['col3']."','".$r1['col4']."','".$r1['c ol5']."')");
}

$insert="INSERT INTO notas (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES ";
file_put_contents($docsql, $insert);
foreach($data_records as $record){
    file_put_contents($docsql, $record) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}

$chng = fopen("nts.sql", "a+") or die("cant open file");
$rmv = fstat($chng);
ftruncate($chng, $rmv['size']-2);
fwrite($chng,';');
fclose($chng);
```

That did the job just fine.  Thank's akm you Rock...